# cassandra opscenter IP address?

Tags: cassandra, opscenter

I installed opscenter on a separate server. I can only access opscenter from the private IP and not from the public IP. How can I enable ospcenter on the public IP instead of a private one.

Answer (score 2):

Can configure the interface in the /etc/opscenter/opscenterd.conf config file: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/opscenter/5.0/opsc/configure/opscConfigProps_r.html

Answer (score 1):

From /etc/opscenter/opscenterd.conf config

```
[webserver]
interface = <public-ip-address>
```